# react router navigate(-1) (useNavigate hook) do not work properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I have problem with `react-router` when I use `navigate(-1)` (`useNavigate` hook).

For example I'm on `'/products'` (`PRODUCTS`), tap on button (using `useNavigate('...')`) and now I'm on `'/products/create'` (`PRODUCT_CREATE`), then I go back using `navigate(-1)`, and sometimes I may get into `'/users'` (`USERS`) or `'/products'` (`PRODUCTS`) randomly.

This is a very fickle thing, maybe you know something about this.

app.routes.ts

```
// ======= private route ======= //
const PrivateRoute: FC<RouteI> = ({ element: Element, session, hasSidebar }) => {
  console.log(session);
  return session ? (
    <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
      <SidebarGrid element={Element} hasSidebar={hasSidebar} />
    </Suspense>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={APP_PATH.SIGN_IN} />
  );
};
```

```
// ======= public route ======= //
const PublicRoute: FC<RouteI> = ({ element: Element, session }) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
    {session ? <Navigate to={APP_PATH.USERS} /> : <Element />}
  </Suspense>
);
```

```
// ======= pages ======= //
const SignInPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/sign-in'));
const ResetPasswordPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/reset-password'));
const ProductsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/products'));
const ProductCreatePage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/product-create'));
const ProductDetailsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/product-details'));
const ProductEditPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/product-edit'));
const ProductTypesPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/product-types'));
const UsersPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/users'));
const UserDetailsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/user-details'));
const ProfilePage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/profile'));
const OrdersPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/orders'));
const AdministrationPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/administration'));
const SubscriptionsPage = React.lazy(() => import('./shared/pages/subscriptions'));

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const session = useSelector(userSessionSelector);
  
  const {
    SIGN_IN,
    PRODUCTS,
    PRODUCT_CREATE,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS,
    PRODUCT_EDIT,
    PRODUCTS_TYPES,
    USERS,
    USER_DETAILS,
    RESET_PASSWORD,
    PROFILE,
    ORDERS,
    ADMINISTRATION,
    SUBSCRIPTIONS
  } = APP_PATH;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session) {
      return;
    }

    RequestNotificationPermissions();
  }, [session]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* PRIVATE */}
      <Route path={PRODUCTS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductsPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={PRODUCT_CREATE} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductCreatePage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={PRODUCT_DETAILS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductDetailsPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={PRODUCT_EDIT} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductEditPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={PRODUCTS_TYPES} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductTypesPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={USERS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={UsersPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={USER_DETAILS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={UserDetailsPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={PROFILE} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProfilePage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={ORDERS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={OrdersPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={ADMINISTRATION} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={AdministrationPage} hasSidebar />} />
      <Route path={SUBSCRIPTIONS} element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={SubscriptionsPage} hasSidebar />} />

      {/* PUBLIC */}
      <Route path={SIGN_IN} element={<PublicRoute session={session} element={SignInPage} />} />
      <Route path={RESET_PASSWORD} element={<PublicRoute session={session} element={ResetPasswordPage} />} />

      {/* DEFAULT */}
      <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to={session ? USERS : SIGN_IN} />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={session ? USERS : SIGN_IN} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

I tries using `navigate()` with option `{ replace: true }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you are navigating *forward* are there sometimes where the user get's navigated to `"/users"` or to `"/signin"` to (presumably) authenticate? What are any reproduction steps?

Comment: @DrewReese '/users' is like default page

Comment: Sorry, I meant `"/signin"` to authenticate, but also `"/users"` for already-authenticated users. Can you clarify the reproductions steps if you can?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
For SPA application I should not use option replace in `navigate('/some/route', { replace: true })`. I delete every `{ replace: true }` in the hole project and it works!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I think all the `Navigate` components between public and private routes in your routes ***should*** be redirect, i.e. REPLACE, actions. I think using normal PUSH actions is leaving the history stack in bad shape, e.g. leaving some "redirect" entries in the history stack that the user can then navigate back to.

```
// ======= private route ======= //
const PrivateRoute: FC<RouteI> = ({ element: Element, session, hasSidebar }) => {
  console.log(session);
  return session ? (
    <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
      <SidebarGrid element={Element} hasSidebar={hasSidebar} />
    </Suspense>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={APP_PATH.SIGN_IN} replace /> // <-- redirect
  );
};
```

```
// ======= public route ======= //
const PublicRoute: FC<RouteI> = ({ element: Element, session }) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
    {session
      ? <Navigate to={APP_PATH.USERS} replace /> // <-- redirect
      : <Element />
    }
  </Suspense>
);
```

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* PRIVATE */}
      <Route
        path={PRODUCTS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductsPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={PRODUCT_CREATE}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductCreatePage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={PRODUCT_DETAILS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductDetailsPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={PRODUCT_EDIT}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductEditPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={PRODUCTS_TYPES}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProductTypesPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={USERS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={UsersPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={USER_DETAILS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={UserDetailsPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={PROFILE}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={ProfilePage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={ORDERS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={OrdersPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={ADMINISTRATION}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={AdministrationPage} hasSidebar />}
      />
      <Route
        path={SUBSCRIPTIONS}
        element={<PrivateRoute session={session} element={SubscriptionsPage} hasSidebar />}
      />

      {/* PUBLIC */}
      <Route
        path={SIGN_IN}
        element={<PublicRoute session={session} element={SignInPage} />}
      />
      <Route
        path={RESET_PASSWORD}
        element={<PublicRoute session={session} element={ResetPasswordPage} />}
      />

      {/* DEFAULT */}
      <Route
        path='/'
        element={<Navigate to={session ? USERS : SIGN_IN} replace />} // <-- redirect
      />
      <Route
        path='*'
        element={<Navigate to={session ? USERS : SIGN_IN} replace />} // <-- redirect
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

### Suggested Improvement

To make the code a bit more ***DRY*** I'd also suggest converting the route protection components into layout route components so you render on of each that wraps a set of nested routes.

Example:

```
// ======= private route ======= //
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router';

const PrivateRoute: FC<RouteI> = ({ hasSidebar }) => {
  const session = useSelector(userSessionSelector);
  console.log(session);
  return session ? (
    <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
      <SidebarGrid element={Outlet} hasSidebar={hasSidebar} />
    </Suspense>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={APP_PATH.SIGN_IN} replace />
  );
};
```

```
// ======= public route ======= //
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router';

const PublicRoute = () => {
  const session = useSelector(userSessionSelector);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
      {session
        ? <Navigate to={APP_PATH.USERS} replace />
        : <Outlet />
      }
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

```
// ======= pages ======= //
...

const AppRoutes = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* PRIVATE */}
      <Route element={<PrivateRoute hasSidebar />}>
        <Route path={PRODUCTS} element={<ProductsPage />} />
        <Route path={PRODUCT_CREATE} element={<ProductCreatePage />} />
        <Route path={PRODUCT_DETAILS} element={<ProductDetailsPage />} />
        <Route path={PRODUCT_EDIT} element={<ProductEditPage />} />
        <Route path={PRODUCTS_TYPES} element={<ProductTypesPage />} />
        <Route path={USERS} element={<UsersPage />} />
        <Route path={USER_DETAILS} element={<UserDetailsPage />} />
        <Route path={PROFILE} element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path={ORDERS} element={<OrdersPage />} />
        <Route path={ADMINISTRATION} element={<AdministrationPage />} />
        <Route path={SUBSCRIPTIONS} element={<SubscriptionsPage />} />
      </Route>

      {/* PUBLIC */}
      <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
        <Route path={SIGN_IN} element={<SignInPage />} />
        <Route path={RESET_PASSWORD} element={<ResetPasswordPage />} />
      </Route>

      {/* DEFAULT */}
      <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={USERS} replace />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Hopefully it's clear how much this simplifies the code and improves readability and maintainability.